# How is this code calculating pi and what principle is it based on?

Tags: c, math, obfuscation

I've stumbled upon this snippet in the signature of a mail:

```
int f[9814],b,c=9814,g,i;long a=1e4,d,e,h;main(){for(;b=c,c-=14;i=printf(
"%04d",e+d/a),e=d%a)while(g=--b*2)d=h*b+a*(i?f[b]:a/5),h=d/--g,f[b]=d%g;}
```

This calculates the output of pi (π):

```
3141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208998628034825342117067982148086513282306647093844609550582231725359408128481117450284102701938521105559644622948954930381964428810975665933446128475648233786783165271201909145648566923460348610454326648213393607260249141273724587006606315588174881520920962829254091715364367892590360011330530548820466521384146951941511609433057270365759591953092186117381932611793105118548074462379962749567351885752724891227938183011949129833673362440656643086021394946395224737190702179860943702770539217176293176752384674818467669405132000568127145263560827785771342757789609173637178721468440901224953430146549585371050792279689258923542019956112129021960864034418159813629774771309960518707211349999998372978049951059731732816096318595024459455346908302642522308253344685035261931188171010003137838752886587533208381420617177669147303598253490428755468731159562863882353787593751957781857780532171226806613001927876611195909216420198938095257201065485863278865936153381827968230301952035301852968995773622599413891249721775283479131515574857242454150695950829533116861727855889075098381754637464939319255060400927701671139009848824012858361603563707660104710181942955596198946767837449448255379774726847104047534646208046684259069491293313677028989152104752162056966024058038150193511253382430035587640247496473263914199272604269922796782354781636009341721641219924586315030286182974555706749838505494588586926995690927210797509302955321165344987202755960236480665499119881834797753566369807426542527862551818417574672890977772793800081647060016145249192173217214772350141441973568548161361157352552133475741849468438523323907394143334547762416862518983569485562099219222184272550254256887671790494601653466804988627232791786085784383827967976681454100953883786360950680064225125205117392984896084128488626945604241965285022210661186306744278622039194945047123713786960956364371917287467764657573962413890865832645995813390478027590099465764078951269468398352595709825822620522489407726719478268482601476990902640136394437455305068203496252451749399651431429809190659250937221696461515709858387410597885959772975498930161753928468138268683868942774155991855925245953959431049972524680845987273644695848653836736222626099124608051243884390451244136549762780797715691435997700129616089441694868555848406353422072225828488648158456028506016842739452267467678895252138522549954666727823986456596116354886230577456498035593634568174324112515076069479451096596094025228879710893145669136867228748940560101503308617928680920874760917824938589009714909675985261365549781893129784821682998948722658804857564014270477555132379641451523746234364542858444795265867821051141354735739523113427166102135969536231442952484937187110145765403590279934
```

Some questions I have regarding this:

- Which mathematical principle it is based upon?
- What sort of iterative approximation is this (which series)?
- Why is the output 2800 characters long?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This appears to be based off of [Dik T. Winter's 160-byte C program](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ealopez-o/math-faq/mathtext/node12.html) to compute the first 800 digits of pi, extended for higher precision.

His original code:

```
int a=10000,b,c=2800,d,e,f[2801],g;main(){for(;b-c;)f[b++]=a/5;
for(;d=0,g=c*2;c-=14,printf("%.4d",e+d/a),e=d%a)for(b=c;d+=f[b]*a,
f[b]=d%--g,d/=g--,--b;d*=b);}
```

can be rewritten more readably thus:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int r[2800 + 1];
    int i, k;
    int b, d;
    int c = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 2800; i++) {
        r[i] = 2000;
    }

    for (k = 2800; k > 0; k -= 14) {
        d = 0;

        i = k;
        for (;;) {
            d += r[i] * 10000;
            b = 2 * i - 1;

            r[i] = d % b;
            d /= b;
            i--;
            if (i == 0) break;
            d *= i;
        }
        printf("%.4d", c + d / 10000);
        c = d % 10000;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

During the `k` loop, this is computing the digits of:

[image]

Which by [Beeler et al. (1972)](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PiFormulas.html) is an approximation of pi:

[image] <sup><sup><sup>[image]</sup></sup></sup> [image]

See here for further details:

- https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/notes/pi/code.html

Answer (score 6):

I'll answer the last question: **"Why is the output 2800 characters long?"**

In the initialization line of the code, we see

```
c=9814
```

Then in the loop condition expression of the `for` loop we see

```
c-=14
```

So the loop subtracts 14 from `c` on each loop, starting from 9814, and stops when `c` reaches zero. But we see that  `9814 / 14` is `701`. Since that termination condition is executed before the start of the first loop, the loop executes `700` times.

The last part of the `for` loop, which usually increments the loop variable, instead executes

```
printf("%04d",e+d/a)
```

So `4` characters of an integer are printed in each loop. Those `4` characters, printed `700` times, result in `2800` characters printed total.